# LaunchServices: no bundle found with identifier new.myApp.com While launching app

Tags: bundle, info.plist, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I am working on an app where I did code signing for the app and got bundle identifier. I added bundle identifier in `.plist` file of project and also in `App Targets` under general settings. But when I run app in simulator, It prints in log

```
LaunchServices: no bundle found with identifier new.myApp.com
```

I tried to add bundle identifier in `.plist` again, but still shows
 same thing. I'm getting lots of problems because of this issue (e.g
 Unable to integrate login with `Facebook` functionality). I don't know whats
 the reason for this. If anyone has any solution, Please suggest me. Why I'm getting this `LaunchServices: no bundle found with identifier`.
 Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have removed storyboard file then adding your custom viewcontroller to window.rootviewcontroller.
Make sure you have removed storyboard file from plist and from general also.

Comment: Yes exactly. Made it working. As Xcode 6.1 doesn't have empty app template. So I took storyboard and then added my custom view controller. Thats why it was showing this.